# How to make the Android-Studio run window (logcat) sticky and prevent it from automatically hiding?

Tags: android-studio, logging, logcat

I have dual screens on my Windows desktop and I like to keep Android Studio run logcat on one of them open all the time.  Every time I hit Run the logcat window automatically hides and I need to click on the tab to make it appear again, which is annoying.  Is there a setting where I can keep the logcat window always visible?

Answer (score 1):

To do that

Simply open the **Logcat** window once more...

Click on the **settings** icon at the far right

[image]

Then select **Pinned Mode** there

[image]

This should work...i hope it helped...

Comment: It is the last tap "Run" I like to use not the original Logcat.  The menu I get is different.  There is a "Window" under "View Mode" which I used to move it to the second screen.  However, the window hides when I run the app.  There is no option that simply says "Pinned Mode"

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when I upgraded my Android Studio from 2021.3.1 to 2022.2.1.

What I discovered is that if you go to `File` > `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `Appearance`, then scroll down... you will see a section named `Tool Windows`:

[image: Settings | Tool Windows]

Simply check the `Show tool windows bars` and you will be able to view (with a single click) at the bottom any of tool windows we came to love (including Logcat):

[image: Tool Windows at the bottom]